# View is caching its previous data when the view is reinvoked with a parameterless View() - when I don't want it to

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a simple POCO model `Person`.

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

The relevant action methods are

```
public IActionResult Register()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Register(Person p)
{
    return View();
}
```

Navigating to `\Home\Register` brings up an HTML form that I fill in and submit. Having submitted the form, I am presented by the same page rather than a blank one. **I wish the form to be blank**.

## Question

Why is the second action method which returns `View()` (without passing any `Person` instance) producing a fully filled-in page? How do I stop that behaviour?

## Edit

```
@model Person

@using (Html.BeginForm(nameof(HomeController.Register), nameof(HomeController).Replace(nameof(Controller), string.Empty), FormMethod.Post))
{
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Age)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

Comment: You may wish to read up on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get . This would solve your issue, and give a better experience to your users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your are using ASP.NET Core MVC, [ModelState](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is automatically filled by asp.net during the submit and applied to the view. To get back an empty form you could just clear it:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Register(Person p)
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View();
}
```